# How can I hide sb.append in email if field is empty in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, email

In one of my forms the answers are optional. How can I get it so that only the fields that have been filled in show on the email that the form sends out?

Code example:

```
sb.Append("<br /><br /><br />Email from: " + txtEmail.Text + "\n");
sb.Append("<br /> <br />Site Name   : " + txtSiteName.Text + "\n");
sb.Append("<br />Contract number   : " + txtContractno.Text + "\n");
sb.Append("<br />Department   : " + txtDepartment.Text + "\n");
```

If no one puts in their department, I dont want the heading and blank space where the answer should go to appear on the email.  However if the department is filled in on the form, then I do want it to appear on the email.  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Two simplest options would be:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDepartment.Text))
    sb.Append("<br />Department  : " + txtDepartment.Text + "\n");
...
```

or

```
sb.Append((!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtDepartment.Text)) ? "<br />..." : string.Empty);
```

Of which the first is probably preferable as it skips the call to append completely if the string's not there.

Comment: Hi - neither of those seem to work for me - I get an error page when I use either.  I am using C#, if that helps?

Comment: If they're not working, try string.IsNullOrEmpty rather than string.IsNullOrWhitespace.  Could be that you're using an older version of C#.